# Java thread wait and notify not working properly?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-safety

I have an application where I implemented myself a connection pool as singleton.
Basically, it has a LinkedList availableConnections where I keep the available connections.

```
    private volatile LinkedList<SocketAdapter> availableConnections = new LinkedList<>();
```

I have methods getConnection and returnConnection.

The problem is when I try to get the connection (from a request thread), I synchronize the list availableConnections and check if it's empty. If so, I do availableConnections.wait().

```
    public SocketAdapter getConnection() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (availableConnections) {
            while (availableConnections.isEmpty()) {
                availableConnections.wait();
            }
            return availableConnections.removeFirst();
        }
    }
```

When the connection is finished using try -> finally, I return the connection

```
    public void returnConnection(SocketAdapter socket) {
        synchronized (availableConnections) {
            availableConnections.add(socket);
            availableConnections.notify();
        }
    }
```

The problem is when the wait wakes up, sometimes the list is empty:

```
1 - 14:27:44.593484500 - [Thread6] - *MFConnection - Getting socket 1 - availableConnections: 0
2 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread6] - *MFConnection - END - returnConnection socket1
3 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread6] - returnSyncConnection - availableConnections.notify() - Returning socket 1
4 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread6] - *MFConnection - START - Sync getConnection()
5 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread6] - *MFConnection - Getting socket 1 - availableConnections: 0
6 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread0] - *MFConnection - isEmpty() - wait() - AWAKE - availableConnections: 0
7 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread0] - *** EMPTY
8 - 14:27:44.802258800 - [Thread0] - *MFConnection - isEmpty() - wait()
...
9 - 14:27:45.578528600 - [Thread0] - *MFConnection - isEmpty() - wait() - AWAKE - availableConnections: 1
10 - 14:27:45.579679600 - [Thread0] - *MFConnection - Getting socket 2 - availableConnections: 0
```

We can see on log line 3, Thread6 returned the connection on availableConnections and called notify(). Right after, this same Thread6 was able to get connection on line 4 and 5.

On line 6, the other Thread0 (that was notified, i suppose) wakes up but see an empty list and get's back to wait().

This Thread0 wakes up (this time) after 1 second, on line 9.

Sometimes in my test it takes 10 seconds and I'm holding a request for that time until some notify() activate this thread back.

Any thoughts on this?

I didn't use volatile at first but than I added.

I'm expecting the thread follow the wait order and just wakes up then there's a connection available, that should happen right after someone return the connection.

The thread that returns the connection, looks like it has priority, what is bad for what I'm expecting. If it happens, it will not follow the getConnection priority order.

Comment: Re, "...the other Thread0 (that was notified, i suppose) wakes up but see an empty list and get's back to wait()..." That is expected behavior from `wait()`. It is _especially_ to be expected when more than one thread awaits the same condition. That's why your thread calls `wait()` from a loop that re-tests the condition after each time `wait()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

`wait()` / `notify()` doesn't obey any "first in / first out" order.

The documentation for [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) states:

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. **The choice is arbitrary** and occurs at the discretion of the implementation

In your example case it seems that Thread6 was able to finish `returnConnection()`, call `getConnection()` and enter the synchronized block before Thread0 was awakened.

If you need guaranteed ordering of the waiting tasks you could use an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html):

> This class supports an optional fairness policy for ordering waiting producer and consumer threads. By default, this ordering is not guaranteed. However, a queue constructed with fairness set to true grants threads access in FIFO order. Fairness generally decreases throughput but reduces variability and avoids starvation.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of `wait()` explicitly specifies that it can just wake up randomly sometimes.

In general, you should not even be using `wait` and `notify`, but almost certainly should be using higher level constructs from `java.util.concurrent` -- in this case, probably a `Lock` with a `Condition`.

Comment: I used this Lock with Condition and it's working fine now.